# any() function in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and was playing with it until I have a problem with `any()`  function. According to the Python library, the code for it is:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

I created a list: `list = [-1, 1]` and I expected:

```
print any(list) < 0
print any(x < 0 for x in list)
```

would print two `True`'s and the two statements are equivalent. But instead Python printed

```
False
True
```

Why is the first statement False? How is it different from the second one?

Comment: What made you think `any(list) < 0` would be equivalent to `any(x < 0 for x in list)`?

Comment: `any(list) < 0` is not equivalent.` Also avoid using list as a variable name

Comment: You should avoid using `list` as a variable name as that masks the built-in type. I used `lst` in my answer instead, so that I could use the `list()` callable to illustrate what the generator expression produces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`any(list)` returns a boolean value, based only on the contents of `list`. Both `-1` and `1` are true values (they are not numeric 0), so `any()` returns `True`:

```
>>> lst = [1, -1]
>>> any(lst)
True
```

Boolean values in Python are a subclass of `int`, where `True == 1` and `False == 0`, so `True` is **not** smaller than 0:

```
>>> True < 0
False
```

The statement `any(list)` is in no way equivalent to `any(x < 0 for x in list)` here. That expression uses a generator expression to test each element individually against `0`, and there is indeed *one* value smaller than `0` in that list, `-1`:

```
>>> (x < 0 for x in lst)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1077769d8>
>>> list(x < 0 for x in lst)
[False, True]
```

so `any()` returns `True` as soon as it encounters the second value in the sequence produced.

*Note*: You should avoid using `list` as a variable name as that masks the built-in type. I used `lst` in my answer instead, so that I could use the `list()` callable to illustrate what the generator expression produces.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is quite clear. I thought in the first case any() takes <0 before it returns a boolean. Now I feel I asked a very stupid question.

Comment: @syj: Python is very straightforward when it comes to function calls; stuff outside the `(..)` doesn't apply to the call.. :-)

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the docs, `any(list)` returns a *boolean*. You're comparing that boolean to the integer `0`:

```
>>> any(list)
True
>>> True < 0
False
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not realize it returns a boolean. I was thinking it evaluates the condition list[element] < 0 for all elements in list.